Twilio SMS not getting the answer in wait and reply widget
My goal is to send an SMS containing the full Twilio Studio flow via the REST API. While I can successfully send the initial messages, the issue arises when the recipient replies. Their response is not being captured or processed by Twilio, and there is no follow-up interaction. How should I structure the entire process or make some special configuration to ensure that responses to the SMS are captured and that the conversation flow continues as expected?
I tried using the Twilio REST API to trigger a Studio flow by sending an SMS. The first message is delivered successfully, but when I reply to the SMS, my response isn’t processed, and the conversation doesn’t continue. I also found that the flow works when I use a US phone number ('+14236...'), but not when I use my local Peruvian number. When I use my number, I receive the following error: 'TwilioRestException: HTTP 400 error: Unable to create record: 'From' +519... is not a Twilio phone number or Short Code country mismatch.' I’ve read similar questions online, but none of them provided a solution. I would really appreciate any help with this issue.
# Download the helper library from https://www.twilio.com/docs/python/install
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

# Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"]
auth_token = os.environ["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

execution = client.studio.v1.flows(
    "FWXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
).executions.create(to="+1........", from_="+1.......")

print(execution.sid)


That's a strange problem. Would you mind sharing more the details about the Studio flow (screenshot + flow execution log) and the configuration of the phone number that you use? Also, is the US/Peruvian number you refer to the Twilio Sender or the recipient? And if it's the recipient number, what is the sender number?
